# Where is the release keystore located for Android apps?

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

I'm following this tutorial to create a Turn Based Multiplayer game: https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling

Under the Specify client ID settings section, they say to run:

> keytool -list -keystore [path-to-debug-keystore]

That's fine because they also mention the location of the debug keystore: "On Windows, the debug keystore can be found at C:\Users[USERNAME].android\debug.keystore."

They also say to run this command:

> keytool -list -keystore [path-to-production-keystore]

But they don't mention where the release/production keystore is.

...where is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You generate the production key yourself. Read [Sign Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) in the android developer documentation.